# ¿Como expresar en álgebra relacional las personas a las que les gusten al menos dos temas?

Tags: sql

Tengo tres base de datos `Gusta(Persona, Tema)`, `Estudia(Persona, Tema)`, `Odia(Persona,Tema)`. ¿Cómo expresar en álgebra relacional las personas que gustan al menos dos temas en  álgebra relacional?

## Mi intento:

π<sub>Persona</sub>(Gusta) da la personas que gustan cualquier tema. Pienso que para las personas que gustan más de dos temas, sería una cosa como : π<sub>Persona</sub>(π<sub>Persona</sub>(σ<sub>Tema!=Tema</sub>(Gusta)). Pero no estoy seguro... ¿cómo expresar esta relación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad:

1. “ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta)”  nos da la misma tabla, pero con Tema renombrada a Tema2
2. hacemos una "unión natural" entre la tabla original y esta: “Gusta ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta)”
3. filtramos cuando se trata del mismo tema: “σ<sub>Tema≠Tema2</sub>(Gusta ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta))”
4. quedan las tuplas con temas distintos.

Todo junto:

> π<sub>Persona</sub>(σ<sub>Tema≠Tema2</sub>(Gusta ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta)))